# JavaCameraView rendering error

Tags: xml, opencv3.0

I have a problem with javacameraview, i use it for a classifier, i wanna insert in the bottom of the screen a textbox and when the app see a particolar object it can insert there a the name of this.
I modify the activity_main.xml but it's not working.
This is the file modified:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:opencv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="225dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <!--  com.example.name.opencvdetect.CameraModify  -->

    <org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="225dp"
        android:id="@+id/cameraAndroid"
        opencv:show_fps="true"
        opencv:camera_id="any"
        />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/InnerRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="629dp"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDisp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Here where the name of the object must be insert."
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

But when i run it on my phone (Nexus 5) i see the full screen but i don't see the textview can someone help me? Thanks.